# Having some issue with .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

This time, am having a static website that is rooted from a not so renowned hosting. It was paid however. But for some reason... I couldn't understand why does each time I tried to open the page on a browser, any .php file could not be executed properly. It just made me download the .php file instead.

I've asked a friend of mine and she helped me a lot when it comes to .htaccess file. But even if I had it uploaded on my site's file manager... the same thing still occurs.
Does it has something to do with .htaccess that makes me download the .php file instead of showing it on the browser screen?

Any suggestion?

Comment: `Header set Content-Disposition attachment` is this somewhere in your .htaccess? This says to your browser that it should download a file. Other wise contact your host or switch parties since this is really weird behaviour.

Comment: no sir @RickLancee
that code is not included on my .htaccess
so I suppose it really has something to do with the host.

Answer (score 0):

Change your provider it seems that your webhoster has no htaccess and PHP support. Or better ask your webhoster for a bigger package which supports PHP and htaccess.

For checking the htaccess support just write in your .htaccess file the word crash if you get a 500 page on any request htaccess is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server from which you are trying to get the .php file delivered does not have the ability to interpret the php file, and instead offers the file for download.  For example, amazon s3 will DELIVER the php file to you, but will not INTERPRET it and deliver the resultant HTML or what-have-you.

Comment: thanks @Helpful...
It does have phpmyadmin and supports mysql so I suppose the server would consider the use of a php file.
But this error happened. However if I change the file into .html it would display.

Comment: Yeah, that's really weird behavior then - have you tried without any .htaccess file?

Comment: yes... but the nothing's change. in fact this issue came even before I add the .htaccess file. yet this is just a simple login form.

I've checked the content-type but found no suspecting codes in it...

Comment: Do you have examples of other php files working on the host/your website, specifically?  A .htaccess from some ancestor directory may be throwing things off.